# Python Multiprocessing Lists Values Aren't Being Retained

Tags: python, multiprocessing

functions `def refresh_image_list(self)` and `def refresh_server_list(self)`: both update `self.images` and `self.servers` in their respected order. They do at the time of object creation with no issues.

I can call them with Python's multiprocessing Process with no issues ether... except for one... the info appended to self.images and  self.servers does not retain. Again, it's not an issue when I don't use the multiprocessing... it's only when I use the multiprocessing Process. I veriefied that the functions do run correctly when running them with Process by switching the functions to `image_list()` and `server_list()` and they printed out the lists successfully. But again, the info in the `self.servers` and self.images did not retain afterwards.

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self, username, api, pipe_object):
        self.images = []
        self.servers = []
        self.images_timestamp = None
        self.servers_timestamp = None
        #needed a dictionary instead of 
        #list/tuple. This works best for 
        #the generator.
        self.regions = {
                "DFW" : pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers("DFW"),
                "ORD" : pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers("ORD"),
                "SYD" : pyrax.connect_to_cloudservers("SYD")
                }

        p1 = Process(target = self.refresh_server_list, args=())
        p2 = Process(target = self.refresh_image_list, args=())
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p2.join()
        p1.join()

    flavors = None 


    def refresh_server_list(self):
    self.servers = []
        self.servers_timestamp = time.strftime(
            "%I:%M:%S", time.localtime()
        )
        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print "\nRefreshing server cache...hold on!"

        for region, value in self.regions.iteritems():
            region_servers = value.servers.list()
            for region_servers in generator(region_servers, region):
                self.servers.append(region_servers)

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print "\nServer cache completed!"

    def server_list(self):
        if not self.servers:
            self.refresh_server_list()

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print_header("Active Server List", "-")
            for srv in self.servers:
                print "\nName: %s" % srv.name
                print "Created: %s" % srv.created
                print "Progress: %s" % srv.progress
                print "Status: %s" % srv.status
                print "URL: %s" % srv.links[0]["href"]
                print "Networks: %s" % srv.networks
            print "\nLast Refresh time: %s" % self.servers_timestamp

    def refresh_image_list(self):
    self.images = []
        self.images_timestamp = time.strftime(
            "%I:%M:%S", time.localtime()
        )
        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
           # print_header("Active Image List", "-")
            print "\nRefreshing image cache...hold on!"

        for region, value in self.regions.iteritems():
            region_images = value.images.list()
            for region_images in generator(region_images, region):
                self.images.append(region_images)

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print "\nImage cache completed!"

    def image_list(self):
        if not self.images:
            self.refresh_image_list()

        with Redirect(self.pipe_object):
            print_header("List Images", "-")
            for img in self.images:
                print (
                    str(self.images.index(img)+1) + ") "
                    + "Name: %s\n    ID: %s Status: %s" %
                    (img.name, img.id, img.status)
                    )
            print "\nLast Refresh time: %s" % self.images_timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obvious because when you start a new process it doesn't share the same address space and the process data **is copied**, hence you **cannot** modify the original object in the main process form the child processes. If you were using threads that would work, since they share the same address space.

If you want to modify an object you must share it using the `Manager` class, or you can use `multiprocessing.Array` & Co.

Alternatively, instead of sharing the lists you can return the *new* modified lists with some kind of output using a [queue/pipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) or whatever you are comfortable with in the multiprocessing module.

Comment: I intend to use reuse the functions later on under normal circumstances(without multiprocessing). I guess Manager would be the best choice so I would not have to modify the original functions?

Comment: Also, someone said I should not do this in __init__. To multiprocessing done when the object is created, where else go I place this?

Comment: @dman If you don't want to put it in `__init__` you may create an `initialize()` method that creates the processes and does the work. Alternatively you could launch the subprocesses only when you need the server list for the first time.